# How to send some text from command to syslog in router?

Tags: python, tcl, router, cisco

I would like to use command show interface in router and i like to capture some text from the result of command like

Router#show interface
interface A is down
interface B is UP
interface A speed 100GB status stable
interface B speed 10GB status unstable

i need to capture to send msg form this result to syslog like
interface A is down speed 100GB status stable

How to do in cisco router (ios-xe) , or use python or EEM/TCL script in router ?

can i send log every 5mins.

in router can custom msg to syslog by command is "send log "text""

thank you for your help.

i can do only cisco command. i never know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

I've only done EEM scripts to run literal actions and not generate messages, but you should be able to drop the following into an EEM script:

```
action 4 syslog msg "Insert your text here."
```

Had to do a quick search, but here's the source: https://community.cisco.com/t5/networking-documents/cisco-eem-basic-overview-and-sample-configurations/ta-p/3148479

I'm not sure what syslog level those messages are, but to configure your router it's something like this (logging level may vary).

```
logging host <ip-of-syslog>
logging trap 5
```

If you're ultimately trying to monitor that interface going up and down, I wouldn't do an EEM script but rather generate syslog messages with the right logging level (5 / notification should do it) and then alert / parse it out with your syslog server.  It's un-necessary overhead to write a script for it.

I have the Python code to send sample syslog messages to a syslog server, but if you're trying to get output from a router standard syslog or potentially EEM is the better route in my opinion.

Hope this helps.